# osmdroid shows flickering overlay tiles

Tags: android, overlay, tiles, osmdroid, flicker

I am using osmdroid version 6.1.2 to show a map application under android (tested on different devices with android versions from 4.0.3, 7.0, 8.0 up to 9.0, no difference concerning the effect).

As long as I use only one main layer (e.g. MAPNIK), everything is OK. But when I add an overlay (e.g. PUBLIC_TRANSPORT), some of the map tiles (which ones is unpredictable) are showing flickering contents. In fact the map layers for these tiles are replaced several times per second with different old contents, probably from the cache. The background map remains stable all the time, but the overlay is running riot.

This effect remains, even after all tiles are downloaded completely - checked with TileStates.getUpToDate();

mapView.invalidate(); doesn't help either.

Code snippets (simplified for better overview):

```
// background map
MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
MapTileSource mapTileSource = new MapTileSource(this);
mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);

// overlay map
ITileSource iTileSource = TileSourceFactory.PUBLIC_TRANSPORT;
MapTileProviderBasic provider = new MapTileProviderBasic(getApplicationContext());
provider.setTileSource(iTileSource);
TilesOverlay tilesOverlay = new TilesOverlay(provider, this.getBaseContext());
tilesOverlay.setLoadingBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
mapView.getOverlays().add(tilesOverlay);
```

and in the layout.xml

```
<org.osmdroid.views.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed by the osmdroid team, as of release 6.1.6. See [here](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/1509).